# What is the purpose of wp_usermeta key: wp_user_level

Tags: database, wordpress, metadata

I'm trying to optimize our database because we have a lot of users and the wp_usermeta table is getting really really large. I notice that every single new users gets a row added with the key `wp_user_level` but when I do a multi-file search of my entire site, that key isn't referenced a single time. So I'm stumped. What the is it? And can I get rid of it without anything catching on fire?

Comment: I believe `wp_user_level` is obsolete now: http://codex.wordpress.org/User_Levels BTW, you can have better answer on wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: I got the sense that is the case. Is it still created on registration for backwards compatibility?

Comment: could be. I think you will get more definitive answer by talking to devs on IRC.